# Form warning when page is refreshed -- despite no data entered?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm afraid I'm missing something basic about html/angular forms. I've created the following form. When I refresh, even if no user data is entered, I get a warning that I entered data into my page: "the page that you're looking for used information that you entered...".

I'm not worried about surpressing this prompt generally, but only when a user actually doesn't enter any data.

Thanks so much!

```
<form id="contactForm">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="not required"/>
            <select class="form-control" name="category">
                <option value="wrong">Wrong data</option>
                <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                <option value="inquiry">General Inquiries</option>
            </select>
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control" placeholder="Let us know how to improve"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="submit = 'true'" value="submit" /><br> <span ng-show="submit == 'true'" class="feedback">Thank you! We'll respond to your comments soon.</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Read MORE about `ngModel` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: No idea where the message in question comes from. Not shown in the code

Comment: @charlietfl I think it's the from resubmission prompt he's talking about

Comment: Yep it is the form resubmission prompt. Thanks for the link @AlonEitan!